# Non-continuable exception... What does it mean?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Today I was changing some resources in my RC files (to be more specific, I replaced a PNG file with another one, and then rebuilt the RES file using BRCC32). After rebuilding my application, I tried to run it but I got the following exception:

```
Project Blablabla.exe raised exception class $C00000025 with message non-continuable exception at address blablabla...
```

I'm using madExcept, but this exception wasn't handled by it, and rather by Delphi's internal exception handler. The Event Log window shows that this exception is raised in my main thread. My only resort has been to replace the suspecting PNG file with the original one so far. What is this exception? What is not continuable? Application load? Reading resources? Loading DLLs/Packages? Does anyone know? Google isn't kind to me today...

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/98840; Does your application manage to start, or does it die while loading? If it dies while loading, try disabling the anti-virus. If it dies at Runtime, any chance it happens while reading the PNG? Maybe there's a combination of corruption in the PNG and bugs in the PNG library causing stack corruption, as the MS KB article stipulates.

Comment: @CosminPrund The application fails to load. I've tried disabling A/V, to no avail. I'll take a look @ that MS KB. Thanks